# How can I replace the keyboard lights with 12 volt lights?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, led, keyboard

I had an idea in mind: connecting the three keyboard lights to three external lights that operate on a 12-volt current by using an NPN transistor circuit. However, when I tried to implement the idea, I encountered an issue with the keyboard. The current was being cut off from the negative terminal instead of the positive terminal. I want to implement it using PNP transistors, but as a beginner, I have searched a lot and couldn't find a solution. I am currently looking for a solution to apply this circuit.
The current remains continuous from the positive terminal; it is cut off from the negative terminal... So how can I create the circuit?
Thank you in advance for your help.
[image]

Comment: Please include the schematic you implemented (you can use the schematic editor if you just want to include the relevant portion).

Comment: replace the LEDs with optocouplers

Comment: @JYelton
I couldn't add the photo in the comment, don't know how

Comment: @jsotola
Thank you very much my friend, I will try and tell you the result

Comment: @SaadEss - Hi, You had been asked to add your schematic and you commented above: "*I couldn't add the photo in the comment, don't know how*". As that will be useful for anyone trying to help you, it should not be added in a comment anyway. On Stack Exchange, questions should be updated and improved by editing them to add new information, clarify ambiguities etc. Therefore please click [edit] - then on a PC, press Ctrl+G to upload an image (e.g. a clear photo of a hand-drawn schematic) or press Ctrl+M to start the built-in schematic editor. On Android/iOS, the schematic editor is unavailable.